# Com Error creating Visual Studio 2010 Plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins

I am attempting my first Visual Studio 2010 plugin and am attempting to reference the ActiveSolutionProjects like so

```
    private DTE2 _applicationObject;

        public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
        {
             _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
             ...
        }

   private void load()
   {         
       var theProjects = (System.Array)_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;
       ...
    }
```

The

```
var theProjects = (System.Array)_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;
```

line fails with

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
ErrorCode -2147467259
```

Any idea how I fix this error?

Comment: Edit your snippet and show how you got the reference to the DTE2 object.

Comment: This seems to be related to the ActiveSolutionProjects being null. If I double click a file in the solution to load it, then the above works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is there is no active solution selected and a null reference issue. I just wrapped the call in an exception handler and am investigating how to set the active solution through automation.